# Why is there still an ambiguity in definitions when you partial a class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the follow class generated by Entity Framework

```
 public partial class Album
 {
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
 }
```

I also have the following in another class

```
 public class Album
 {
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
 }
```

I would like to know why Visual Studio is giving me an error about ambiguity and an already existing definition when the generated class is a partial class. I've tried making the non-partial class partial but it still gave me an error.

Error: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Album'; another partial declaration of this type exists

Comment: What error, this one? _"Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Album'; another partial declaration of this type exists"_

Comment: The reason for that is because Visual Studio doesn't know which one to use.  It doesn't matter if it's a partial class or not.  As long as it's accessible to where ever you called it, it will still cause confusion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes!

Comment: @Auguste what's weird is that I followed a Microsoft Virtual Academy tutorial and it was fine for the guy in the video. Same code and every thing

Comment: @AlfieMcNarutoad: then add it to your question. But it should be solved by making it also `partial`. However, you are using the same properties. That doesn't work since it would be the same as declaring the same properties twice in the same class. So you should get compiler errrors like this: _"The type 'Album' already contains a definition for 'AlbumID'"_ What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah I am getting that error. Mind you I'm just following a MVA video about Entity Framework and, like I said, the guy didn't have errors. Same properties in the class and stuff

Answer (score 2):

A "Partial" class is just a way to break code in one class up between files.  You may do this for ease of use, or even for code generation, but that's all it really does.

*ALL* class definitions with that name in that namespace for that class need to be tagged as "partial" for [it to work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Your second class "breaks" the partial functionality because it isn't marked as partial, but exists with the same name in the same namespace.  You've also got duplicate definitions of properties, which will cause your NEXT error once you fix this one.

Which brings up the obvious question?  Why do you believe you need two classes doing the same thing in the same namespace?

Comment: If it's not too much, try taking a look at https://youtu.be/hYUASO5dnAk?t=52m15s he has two classes doing the same thing and creates no error. I'm just wondering how he's not getting any

Comment: I'm not going to watch the full hour.  I strongly suspect his two classes are in different namespaces.  Worth reading:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx  - "All the parts must use the partial keyword."